# PHPExcel CSV to XLSX

Tags: php, csv, phpexcel, xlsx

I have a problem converting file feom CSV to XLSX format:

Index.php

```
<?php
if (!isset($_FILES["file"]))
{
?>
<html>
    <body>
        <h1>Convert CSV to XLSX</h1>
        <form action="index.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <input type="file" name="file"/>
            <input type="submit"/>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
<?php
    exit;
}

//obtain PHPExcel from http://phpexcel.codeplex.com
require_once('Classes\PHPExcel.php');
require_once('CSVToExcelConverter.php');

if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0)
{
    echo "Error: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"];
    exit;
}

try
{
    header('Content-type: application/ms-excel');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.'example.xlsx');

    CSVToExcelConverter::convert($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], 'php://output');
} catch(Exception $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

CSVToExcelConverter.php

```
class CSVToExcelConverter
{
    /**
     * Read given csv file and write all rows to given xls file
     * 
     * @param string $csv_file Resource path of the csv file
     * @param string $xls_file Resource path of the excel file
     * @param string $csv_enc Encoding of the csv file, use utf8 if null
     * @throws Exception
     */
    public static function convert($csv_file, $xls_file, $csv_enc=null) {
        //set cache
        $cacheMethod = PHPExcel_CachedObjectStorageFactory::cache_to_phpTemp;
        PHPExcel_Settings::setCacheStorageMethod($cacheMethod);

        //open csv file
        $objReader = new PHPExcel_Reader_CSV();
        if ($csv_enc != null)
            $objReader->setInputEncoding($csv_enc);
        $objPHPExcel = $objReader->load($csv_file);
        $in_sheet = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet();

        //open excel file
        $objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();
        $out_sheet = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet();

        //row index start from 1
        $row_index = 0;
        foreach ($in_sheet->getRowIterator() as $row) {
            $row_index++;
            $cellIterator = $row->getCellIterator();
            $cellIterator->setIterateOnlyExistingCells(false);

            //column index start from 0
            $column_index = -1;
            foreach ($cellIterator as $cell) {
                $column_index++;
                $out_sheet->setCellValueByColumnAndRow($column_index, $row_index, $cell->getValue());
            }
        }

        //write excel file
        $objWriter = new PHPExcel_Writer_Excel2007($objPHPExcel);
        $objWriter->save($xls_file);
    }
}
```

CSV File format: [CSV file opened with Excel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EsU8Y.png)

[xlsx file I get after conversion](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iMGtm.png)

Basicaly I would like to get output similar to original csv file, but in xmlx format, how to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "default" separator for reading a CSV file in PHPExcel is a comma (`,`). Your CSV file is using something other than a comma - perhaps a tab (`"\t"`), which is also commonly used for such files).

If the values isn't a comma (and we can't tell from an image of the file viewed in MS Excel) then you have to tell PHPExcel explicitly what that separator is before loading.

e.g.

```
$objReader->setDelimiter("\t");
```

Comment: Thanks for answer! That made things a lot more clear for me!