# Export huge data into xlsx

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, phpexcel, laravel-excel

I need to export a huge dataset from a MySQL database table with MYISAM engine into a `.xlsx` file in Laravel.

I'm using the [maatwebsite/laravel-excel](http://www.maatwebsite.nl/laravel-excel/docs/export) package, which is based on [PHPExcel](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel).

The datased consits of about 500,000 rows with 93 columns (around 46,500,000 cells), and quite a few calculations regarding the header structure.

This is the code I'm currently using:

```
// $excel_data contains some data regarding the project, nothing relevant here
$output = Excel::create('myproject-' . $excel_data->project->name . '-'.date('Y-m-d H:i:s') . '-export', function($excel) use($excel_data) {

        // Set the title
        $excel->setTitle($excel_data->project->name . ' Export');

        $excel->sheet('Data', function($sheet) use($excel_data) {

            $rowPointer = 1;

            $query = DB::table('task_metas')
                ->where([
                    ['project_id', '=', $excel_data->project->id],
                    ['deleted_at', '=', null]
                ])
                ->orderBy('id');

            $totalRecords = $query->count();
            // my server can't handle a request that returns more than 20k rows so I am chunking the results in batches of 15000 to be on the safe side
            $query->chunk(15000, function($taskmetas) use($sheet, &$rowPointer, $totalRecords) {
                // Iterate over taskmetas
                foreach ($taskmetas as $taskmeta) {
                    // other columns and header structure omitted for clarity
                    $sheet->setCellValue('A' . $rowPointer, $rowPointer);
                    $sheet->setCellValue('B' . $rowPointer, $taskmeta->id);
                    $sheet->setCellValue('C' . $rowPointer, $taskmeta->url);

                    // Move on to the next row
                    $rowPointer++;
                }
                // logging the progress of the export
                activity()
                    ->log("wrote taskmeta to row " . $rowPointer . "/" . $totalRecords);

                unset($taskmetas);
            });
        });

    });

    $output->download('xlsx');
```

According to the log, the rows are successfully written into the file, however the file creation itself takes a long time. So long in fact, that it doesn't finish it in 1 hour (that's the max execution time of this function).

Exporting it to csv works great, in about 10 minutes it compiles the file & downloads it, however I can't work with that - the output file *needs* to be `xlsx`.

What can I do to speed up the file creation process? I'm also open to other alternatives as long as I can achieve the same results.

Comment: PHP can not do everything + this is probably heavy on memory, export CSV and process it using Python, I bet it will be 20-30 lines of code... google around. Heck do it all in Python, I am PHP guy but I would rely on Python in this case since its a long running job...

Comment: Why not stick with the csv and convert it to xlsx after creating. Here are some resources for converting from csv to xlsx https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33815465/phpexcel-csv-to-xlsx https://www.phpclasses.org/browse/file/40495.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have 3 suggestions:

1. Using [cursor](https://laravel.com/api/5.2/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.html#method_cursor) (although till today, I have not found out if its better than chunk - maybe your case might validate this) - Sincerely I only used this one and its with Eloquent.
2. reduce the size of the chunk. I think loading 15000 records in memory is already an issue.
3. Create the excel file first, then use `rows()` method on the sheet to append multiple rows. (this might not work well as it requires an array)