# PHPExcel converter not working fine

Tags: php, phpexcel

I try to convert csv to xlsx using PHPExcel tools, when i run the script i got error and i got chinese font in excel file after convert:
[Error PHP EXECL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4yJ73.png)
here is my code :

```
<?php
include 'PHPExcel/PHPExcel/IOFactory.php';

$objReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader('CSV');

// If the files uses a delimiter other than a comma (e.g. a tab), then tell the reader
$objReader->setDelimiter("\t");
// If the files uses an encoding other than UTF-8 or ASCII, then tell the reader
$objReader->setInputEncoding('UTF-16LE');

$objPHPExcel = $objReader->load('myfilebeforeconvert.csv');
$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel5');
$objWriter->save('afterconvert.xls');
```

what my fault ? please tell me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have provided little information but you can check this [example for help](https://www.phpclasses.org/package/7528-PHP-Convert-CSV-files-to-Excel-using-PHPExcel-library.html).

This might also help, [check this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33815465/phpexcel-csv-to-xlsx)